# Can I use the Private Key Certificate of Web App to sign JWT?

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-oauth

I am developing Push Notification Server for Chrome browser. On Google Cloud Console I have registered my application as web application and downloaded the private key Certificate. Can I use this certificate to sign the JWT request?

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it's generally not a good idea to share the private key for multiple purposes.

From Microsoft (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh341466.aspx):

> It is a public key infrastructure (PKI) best practice to not share the private key for >multiple purposes. Therefore, do not use the service communication certificate that you >installed on the federation server as the token-signing certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I was able to sign the JWT message using Private Key Certificate. And I also got the AccessToken back from the server