# What certificate store should I use to store a certificate for signing/encrypting JWT tokens?

Tags: iis, jwt, ssl-certificate, iis-8, x509

I'm adding support for JWT tokens in my Web Application, and I have an X509 certificate which it needs for signing those tokens.

I have rejected the idea of using the same certificate we use for HTTPs (see [Can I use the Private Key Certificate of Web App to sign JWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448949/can-i-use-the-private-key-certificate-of-web-app-to-sign-jwt)).

I think a self signed certificate should do the trick, in fact I can't see any advantages of a web of trust in this scenario (that doesn't mean there aren't any, I just can't think of any).

The web application runs on a farm of web servers. My current plan is to generate a self signed cert and put the X509 certificate into the certificate store in Windows on each machine. Our IT department are checking, but they think they can roll that out to all the Web Servers in the farm using Group Policy. So this seems like a feasible plan.

The certificate store in windows looks pretty confusing to me. I think there are two options:

1) Put it in "My" store for the user under which the IIS App pool run. There are many app pools, so potentially the certificate will be in many stores.

2) Put it under the LocalMachine store, and then grant explicit access to the specific certificate for the IIS user(s).

3) Something else I can't think of.

Is there a "correct" place for these type of certs, and if so where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual CertificateStore for signing certificates is the **My** store. I normally place them in **LocalMachine** location, but it is probably safer to put them in the certificate store for the Application Pool identity itself.

I would then give the Application Pool read-only access to this certificate only (right click certificate, then 'All Tasks' > 'Manage Private Keys', then add your Application Pool identity and give 'Read' permissions only.